# Auto renewal verification in app purchase iphone 

Tags: iphone, transactions, in-app-purchase, verification, renewal

I am working on one app in which i have implemented the in app purchase and also successfully verified the receipt.

I have done the auto renewal subscription in which I want to know how I can check the user subscription is active or not?

In order to verify the receipt i need the receipt from the SKPaymentTransaction. So my question is that how could I can check when user returns to my app that he still has subscription or it expired.

or simply which method can give me the user transaction property of SKPaymentTransaction on load of my view so i can verify the receipt.

Thanks in advance,
Satish

Comment: Hi Satish. Is there a way to get receipt after the transaction was done but app was unable to save it locally or on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it in the following way...

I save the transaction receipt in userdefaults when user first time subscribes to the subscription and when later I need to check for the subscription activation I use that receipt which tells me the latest expiry day..

Hope this will help...

Comment: Hi Satish, Thanks very much for the info, could u please post some code / link on how to use the receipt and check the expiry date for subscription activation. Thanks again.

Comment: According to apple documentation that would work only when not restoring transaction because on restore there is no expiration date.
So, It's not a good solution.

You can read it on the next link on "expires_date":
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html

Comment: What about the case when a user wants to use his subscription on another device?